# WPF. Show video from camera device. Performance and resources

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, video, video-capture

I need to add control to my WPF application which will show video in real time from camera device in 720x580 resolution.

The main requirements:

1. It should be really quick and show
   good performance.
2. Full screen mode
       video with hi resolution.
3. I can see some wpf controls over
           video control when it in fullscreen mode.
4. 720x580 resolution supported.
5. Not take much processor resources!

I saw some controls in the internet. But i need to have some feedbacks about them. Please give advice if you used some. What control or library you prefer and which can meet my requirements. 
Thanks for replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the VideoCaptureElement in [WPF MediaKit](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit)

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [ffmediaelement](https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement). I use to view video from capture device.
In the sample application, controls are located above the video, but I do not have a personal experience.
Example of setting up a capture device - it's very simple:

```cs
Media.OnMediaOpening(s, e) =>
{
    e.Options.Input["framerate"] = "25";
    e.Options.Input["video_size"] = "720x580";
    e.Options.Input["pixel_format"] = "yuyv422";
};
Media.Source = new Uri("device://dshow/?video=Osprey-460e Video Device 1C");
```

Comment: While this links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.